# Mostrar URL acortada

Tags: c#, windows-forms, aplicación-escritorio

traigo una consulta. Tengo una interfaz en la cual poseo dos TextBox, uno en el cual se ingresa una url larga y el otro en el que se muestra la url acortada luego de presionarse el botón. Este código en un Form de C#, quisiera saber como hago para mostrar la url corta en el TextBox.

```
private void btnAcortar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//botón
        {
            string urlCor = txtUrlLarga.Text;
            Acortar(urlCor);
        }

        public static string Acortar(string url)//método para acortar 
        {
            string tinyUrl = url;
            string api = "la api de tiny=";
            try
            {
                var request = WebRequest.Create(api + url);
                var res = request.GetResponse();
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    tinyUrl = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exp);
            }
            return tinyUrl;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se si he entendido bien la pregunta, pero si la función Acortar, devuelve correctamente la URL corta, solo tienes que asignarle el valor al TextBox de la URL corta, algo así:

```
   private void btnAcortar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//botón
        {
            string urlCor = txtUrlLarga.Text;
            txtUrlCorta.Text = Acortar(urlCor);
        }
```

Comment: Vale, tienes la razón. Me estaba olvidando de eso. Mil gracias

Answer (score 2):

Te falta pasarle al Textbox el valor del metodo Acortar(urlCor), ya que este mismo devuelve un string.

```
 private void btnAcortar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//botón
    {
            string urlCor = txtUrlLarga.Text;
            txtUrlCorta.Text = Acortar(urlCor);
    }
```